# django-paypal signals not firing

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I have tried for hours to get my signals to work with django-paypal.

Here is my signals.py (which is imported in my urls.py):

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful, payment_was_flagged

@receiver(payment_was_successful)
def confirm_admin_payment(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'SUCCESS: %s' % sender.payer_email

@receiver(payment_was_flagged)
def payment_flagged(sender, **kwargs):
    print "FLAGGED: %s" % sender.payer_email

print "signals.py has been imported"
```

When I use PayPal's IPN simulator, I know the transaction works because I can go into the database, look at the paypal_ipn table and see the transaction entered just fine, so the signals SHOULD be working.

I have also tried both dcramer's and johnboxall's versions of django-paypal, but still no joy.

I'm out of ideas, I've put hours into researching and trying to figure this thing out. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I had some problems with signals and found this vid got me back on track:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwp8k5GQoNU&feature=related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See for errors/warnings in payment transaction. Signal `payment_was_successful` fired only when there is no flags on transaction, even if flags wasn't critical at all (f.e. if your `settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL` != transaction reciever email).

You may debug `standard.ipn.models.PayPalIPN.send_signals` method using pdb at start, is it fired at all? Don't be shine to modify third-party-code for debugging purposes.

Comment: In the standard.ipn.models.send_signals I added a few print statements (one in the beginning of the function, the end, and then one for each if statement within payment_was_successful and payment_was_flagged). When testing with the ipn simulator, it prints the signals start, the payment_was_successful (or payment_was_flagged if invalid paypal_receiver_email), and then signals finished. However, my signals.py still never print their messages.

Comment: After using pdb and doing some other testing, I can get it to work when my signals are placed in paypal.standard.ipn.views. Does my 'import symbols' supposed to be something different then?